# Add ons for google spreadsheet is not showing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

i read about developing add ons using google apps script.its mentioned that in new spreadsheets addons are automatically enabled and when i create new spreadsheet there is no addon tab but when i create a google doc there is a addon tab enabled.can any one please tell how to enable add on feature in recent created google spreadsheets .here is screen shot of no addon tab in spreadsheet

[image]

Comment: Looks like the spreadsheet is still loading.

Answer (score 0):

Add-ons is a feature of the new version of spreadsheets, it seems you are still using the old version. New version has a small green icon in the right bottom corner (small check v).

Comment: How to switch to new version please guideline ??

Comment: by default now every user is switched to new version but still its creating old files in my drive why ??